# Sending data to modal window by clicking a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I cuurently have the following code which makes an ajax call tothe controller which is working fine.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Add to Wishlist", "Add", "Wishlist", new { productId = Product.ProductId }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "breadcrumbs", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @class = "button" })
```

Now I need to change this code and allow the user to also add some extra data along with product Id.

Now the requirement is to open a modal popup when 'add to wishlist' link is clicked and in the modal window show a dropdownlist and a textbox and once user fills them and clicks a submit button in modal popup, then send the data to the controller.

Now, my page has multiple links like this and all links have different productId.

My first problem how do I send the product Id to the modal popup.

Thanks
Arnab

Answer (score 0):

In your main view (one you launching modal from):

```
TempData["ProdId"] = <your product id>
```

In your modal (or popup) dialog:

```
var ProdId = (int)TempData["ProdId"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but how do I add the tempdata in the client side from a link click

Comment: Also in the modal popup I will probably be having a textboxfor and dropdownlistfor and a submit button, how do I call the 'var prodId' on submit click

Comment: What I wrote is on the client side. You don't do it on click, you do it before clicking, once you know the Id, you store it in TempData. Once you need it in your modal - you retrieve it as shown above. Please let me know if you have any difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the normal link by using the `Html.ActionLink` helper method

```
@Html.ActionLink("Add to Wishlist", "Add", "Wishlist",
                           new { @id=product.ProductId},new { class="modelLink"})
```

Now do some javascript to listen to the click event of this link and then open the Dialog and send whatever parameter you want. the below code is opening an Model Popup ([jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (that means, you need to include jQuery UI library for this code to work)) and it is sending 2 parameters to the `Add` action method of `WishList` controller. Whatever you are returning from the Add action method will be shown to the Model dialog.

```
$(function(){    
  $('a.modelLink').click(function(){

     var item=$(this);

     var url=item.attr("href")+"&anotherParam=unicorn";

        var dialog = $("#dialog");
        if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
            dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
        }
        dialog.load(
            url,
            {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({                       
                    close: function (event, ui) {                            
                        dialog.remove();
                    },
                    modal: true,
                    width: 460
                });
            }
        );
    }); 

});
```